# How to pass a list of files as parameters to a powershell script

Tags: powershell

How does one pass a list of files as parameters to a Powershell script?

```
param
(
    [String[]]$files
)

echo $files
```

When I try to run it

```
PS D:\> & '.\merge outputs.ps1' *.dat
```

it prints

```
*.dat
```

but I expected something similar to

```
file1.dat
file2.dat
...
fileN.dat
```

Comment: Are you going to process the files one-by-one?

Comment: No, I will merge them all together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two solutions presented thusfar (even though one is accepted and both have upvotes) do not really provide an adequate solution to the question--they both make you jump through hoops. The question as posed stated that by *just putting* `*.dat` on the commmand line, how can one make the underlying code treat it *like you would expect*. That is, how to make the code *simply do the right thing*. With other shells and other cmdlets, all you do is `*.dat`, not like this:

```
foobar(fizzbuzz[--brobdingnag*!& '\''*.dat''`])
```

(OK, I exaggerate to make a point:-) But there is an easy way to just do the right thing--check if wildcards are used and then just expand them:

```
param
(
    [String[]]$files
)
$IsWP = [System.Management.Automation.WildcardPattern]::ContainsWildcardCharacters($files)
if($IsWP) { 
    $files = Get-ChildItem $files | % { $_.Name }
}
echo $files
```

Comment: To support "foo\*" (or even "*\*"), and if the rest of the script supports full path names, use `$files = Get-ChildItem $files | % { $_.FullName }`.

Comment: Not clear if you are suggesting: (a)  the `$IsWP` check is no longer needed (but it is! have to cover the case of _no_ wildcards) or (b) one should use `FullName` instead of `Name` (but that depends upon your needs; either _could_ work)

Comment: Right. I needed “FullName”, since I wanted to use “*/*” as a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

You can either pass full file name as string

```
& '.\merge outputs' -files (dir *.dat | %{ $_.FullName })
```

Or you can accept FileSystemInfo param in your script

```
param
(
    [System.IO.FileSystemInfo[]]$files
)

Write-Host $files
```

And call:

```
& '.\merge outputs' -files (dir *.dat)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$files = dir *.dat | foreach {$_.fullname}

& '.\merge outputs.ps1' -files $files
```